# Drawing an equilateral triangle inside a circle, an incircle, and two shaded regions

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

A circle is inscribed in an equilateral triangle. Another circle going through the three vertices of the triangle is drawn. One region outside the triangle and within the larger circle is shaded. The region outside the smaller circle and inside the triangle is shaded.

Shading is too hard for me.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (8.,0.) -- (14.,0.) -- (11.,5.196152422706633) -- cycle;
\draw(11.,1.7320508075688779) circle (1.7320508075688772cm);
\draw(11.,1.7320508075688787) circle (3.4641016151377544cm);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw  (8.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw  (14.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw  (11.,5.196152422706633) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (9.5,2.5980762113533165) circle (1.5pt);
\draw  (12.5,2.5980762113533165) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (11.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also want a similar figure with the triangle is replacced by a square.

Comment: Looks good! All the best with your project - let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: How should the filling regions look in the case of a square?

Comment: the same purple colour is good.

Comment: @Thumbolt No, not the color: I meant what regions should be filled?

Comment: one corner inside the square and outside of the smaller circle is shaded. Another shaded is the segment within the large circle outside the square, which is bounded arc and one side of the square. The two shadings are not adjacent.

Comment: @Thumbolt I added an option for the square case. Is it something like that what you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{236,145,191}

\newlength\Radius
\setlength\Radius{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\filldraw[fill=mypurple,even odd rule]
  (0,0) -- node[above] {$R$} (210:\Radius) arc [start angle=210,end angle=90,radius=\Radius] -- (0,0)
  (210:\Radius) -- (90:\Radius) -- (0,0)
  (0,0) -- (30:0.5\Radius) arc [start angle=30,end angle=-90,radius=0.5\Radius] --(0,0)
  (30:0.5\Radius) -- (-30:\Radius) -- (-90:0.5\Radius) -- (0,0);
\draw 
  (0,0) circle [radius=\Radius]
  (0,0) circle [radius=0.5\Radius]
  (90:\Radius) -- (210:\Radius) -- (-30:\Radius) -- cycle
  (0,0) -- (-30:0.5\Radius) node[midway,above] {$r$};
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The square case:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{236,145,191}

\newlength\Radius
\setlength\Radius{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\fill[fill=mypurple,even odd rule,draw=white]
  (0,0) -- (0:{\Radius/sqrt(2)}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\Radius/sqrt(2)] -- (0,0) rectangle (-45:\Radius)
  (0,0) -- (45:\Radius) arc[start angle=45,end angle=135,radius=\Radius] -- (0,0) -- (45:\Radius) -- (135:\Radius) -- cycle ;
\draw
  (0,0) circle [radius=\Radius]
  (225:\Radius) rectangle (45:\Radius)
  (0,0) circle [radius=\Radius/sqrt(2)];
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw 
  (225:\Radius) -- node[above left=-1pt] {$R$} (0,0) -- node[above right=-1pt] {$r$} (-45:{\Radius/sqrt(2)}); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update:

Without `even odd rule`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{236,145,191}

\newlength\Radius
\setlength\Radius{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\fill[fill=mypurple]
  (210:\Radius) arc [start angle=210,end angle=90,radius=\Radius] -- cycle
  (30:0.5\Radius) arc [start angle=30,end angle=-90,radius=0.5\Radius] -- (-30:\Radius) -- cycle;
\draw 
  (0,0) circle [radius=\Radius]
  (0,0) circle [radius=0.5\Radius]
  (90:\Radius) -- (210:\Radius) -- (-30:\Radius) -- cycle
  (0,0) -- (210:\Radius) node[midway,above] {$R$}
  (0,0) -- (-30:0.5\Radius) node[midway,above] {$r$}
  (90:\Radius) -- (90:-0.5\Radius);
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\fill[fill=mypurple]
  (0:{\Radius/sqrt(2)}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\Radius/sqrt(2)] -- (-45:\Radius) -- cycle
  (45:\Radius) arc[start angle=45,end angle=135,radius=\Radius] -- cycle ;
\draw
  (0,0) circle [radius=\Radius]
  (225:\Radius) rectangle (45:\Radius)
  (0,0) circle [radius=\Radius/sqrt(2)];
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw 
  (225:\Radius) -- node[above left=-1pt] {$R$} (0,0) -- node[above right=-1pt] {$r$} (-45:{\Radius/sqrt(2)}); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: one of the two segments should be removed.

Comment: @Thumbolt Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @Thumbolt I updated my answer with another option.

Answer (score 6):

Just for reference...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{rfill/.code={%
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro\g{rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro\b{rnd}%
\definecolor{.}{rgb}{\r,\g,\b}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{.}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={rfill}]
\fill (0:0)   -- (90:1/2)  arc (90:-30:1/2)  -- cycle;
\fill (0:0)   -- (90:1/2)  arc (90:210:1/2)  -- cycle;
\fill (0:0)   -- (210:1/2) arc (210:270:1/2) -- cycle;
\fill (0:0)   -- (270:1/2) arc (270:330:1/2) -- cycle;
\fill (90:1)  -- (90:1/2)  arc (90:30:1/2)   -- cycle;
\fill (90:1)  -- (90:1/2)  arc (90:150:1/2)  -- cycle;
\fill (330:1) -- (30:1/2)  arc (30:-90:1/2)  -- cycle;
\fill (210:1) -- (150:1/2) arc (150:210:1/2) -- cycle;
\fill (210:1) -- (270:1/2) arc (270:210:1/2) -- cycle;
\fill (90:1)  arc (90:-30:1)  -- cycle;
\fill (90:1)  arc (90:210:1)  -- cycle;
\fill (210:1) arc (210:330:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{rfill/.code={%
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro\g{rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro\b{rnd}%
\definecolor{.}{rgb}{\r,\g,\b}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{.}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={rfill}]
\fill (0:0) -- (-45:1/sqrt 2) arc (-45:225:1/sqrt 2) -- cycle;
\fill (0:0) -- (225:1/sqrt 2) arc (225:315:1/sqrt 2) -- cycle;
\fill (90:1/sqrt 2)  arc (90:0:1/sqrt 2)    |- cycle;
\fill (90:1/sqrt 2)  arc (90:180:1/sqrt 2)  |- cycle;
\fill (270:1/sqrt 2) arc (270:360:1/sqrt 2) |- cycle;
\fill (270:1/sqrt 2) arc (270:225:1/sqrt 2) -- (225:1) -- cycle;
\fill (180:1/sqrt 2) arc (180:225:1/sqrt 2) -- (225:1) -- cycle;
\fill (45:1)  arc (45:135:1) -- cycle;
\fill (135:1) arc (135:225:1) -- cycle;
\fill (225:1) arc (225:315:1) -- cycle;
\fill (315:1) arc (315:405:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just another option using `nodes` (`circle` and `regular polygon`) instead of lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{236,145,191}

\newlength\Radius
\setlength\Radius{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]

% circular nodes: minimum size=diameter  
\node[draw, circle, minimum width=2\Radius, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (outer) {};
\node[draw, circle, minimum width=\Radius, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (inner) {};

% regular polygon with 3 sides. minimum size=diameter of circumcircle
\node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, 
      minimum size=2\Radius, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (tri) {};

\filldraw[fill=mypurple] (outer.north) arc[start angle=90, end angle=210, radius=\Radius]
         --cycle;
\filldraw[fill=mypurple] (inner.30) arc[start angle=30, end angle=-90, radius=.5\Radius]
         --(outer.-30)--cycle;

\draw (outer.210)--(inner.30) node[above,pos=.4] {$R$};
\draw (outer.90)--(inner.-90);
\draw (outer.center)--(inner.-30) node[midway,above]{$r$};
\fill (outer.center) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]